# How to make a div grow over another element on mouse hover?

Tags: html, css

I created a development div to put in the footer, created a hover effect that increases it, the problem that it works by itself, but on the site it grows under the top element, I would like it to grow on top or push the element .

site-> https://wjrametais.com.br/

can you help me please, I already broke my head trying to use position, float, among other things.

```css
.developer {
  z-index: 99999 !important;
  background: rgba(55, 55, 55, 1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(39, 39, 39, 1) 0%, rgba(39, 39, 39, 1) 20%, rgba(46, 46, 46, 1) 30%, rgba(39, 39, 39, 1) 40%, rgba(39, 39, 39, 1) 60%, rgba(46, 46, 46, 1) 70%, rgba(39, 39, 39, 1) 80%, rgba(39, 39, 39, 1) 100%);
  height: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.byfoxdev {
  font-family: "montserrat" !important;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: white;
}

.developer:hover .foxdevlogo {
  background-image: url("https://foxdev.com.br/img/foxdev_footer_110x61.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  width: 110px;
  height: 61px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.developer:hover {
  height: 85px;
  margin-top: -60px;
}

.developer:hover .byfoxdev {
  display: visible;
}

.foxdevlogo {
  background-image: url("https://foxdev.com.br/img/foxdev_footer_110x38.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  width: 110px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.fa-heart {
  color: #D9534F;
}

.fa-mug-hot {
  color: #F6E8D6;
}
```

```html
<div class="developer">
  <a href="https://foxdev.com.br">
    <div class="foxdevlogo">
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="byfoxdev">Desenvolvido com <i class="fas fa-heart"></i> e <i class="fas fa-mug-hot"></i> por foxDev</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `overflow: hidden;` from this line

```
.vc_row[data-vc-full-width] {
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
    overflow: hidden; /* <= remove this line */
}
```

Comment: I removed the line from js_composer-min.css but nothing happened = /

Answer (score 0):

```css
.developer {
  z-index: 99999 !important;
  background: rgba(55, 55, 55, 1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(39, 39, 39, 1) 0%, rgba(39, 39, 39, 1) 20%, rgba(46, 46, 46, 1) 30%, rgba(39, 39, 39, 1) 40%, rgba(39, 39, 39, 1) 60%, rgba(46, 46, 46, 1) 70%, rgba(39, 39, 39, 1) 80%, rgba(39, 39, 39, 1) 100%);
  height: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.byfoxdev {
  font-family: "montserrat" !important;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: white;
}

.developer:hover .foxdevlogo {
  background-image: url("https://foxdev.com.br/img/foxdev_footer_110x61.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  width: 110px;
  height: 61px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.developer:hover {
  height: 85px;
}

.developer:hover .byfoxdev {
  display: visible;
}

.foxdevlogo {
  background-image: url("https://foxdev.com.br/img/foxdev_footer_110x38.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  width: 110px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.fa-heart {
  color: #D9534F;
}

.fa-mug-hot {
  color: #F6E8D6;
}
```

```html
<div class="developer">
  <a href="https://foxdev.com.br">
    <div class="foxdevlogo">
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="byfoxdev">Desenvolvido com <i class="fas fa-heart"></i> e <i class="fas fa-mug-hot"></i> por foxDev</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Bimal, thanks for the reply.
The reason I put "margin-top: -60px;" It is for the bar to raise up, as the user is already at the bottom of the page, when the mouse hover, the bar increases down but the page does not follow.
So I found it much nicer that the sense of growth is upwards.